# PhpMyAdmin extra authentication - where is the password saved?

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, phpmyadmin

Some months ago I set up LAMP on my Ubuntu 14.04 DigitalOcean-server. I also installed PhpMyAdmin with an extra security layer.

I have two domains attached to this server. For example1.com/phpmyadmin Safari remembered the username and password for this extra layer, but I can't find it in the saved passwords.
On example2.com I cannot login because I don't know the username and password. Also I would like to change them.

This is the message I get (a popup telling me to enter the credentials):
[image]

I searched the `/etc/phpmyadmin` and `/usr/share/phpmyadmin` folders for files that could have the password or configuration in it, but I didn't found anything useful.

Where is this password saved or how can I change it? (And what is this type of authentication called, so it's easier to Google?)

Comment: This is the image: http://i.stack.imgur.com/5nPlV.png

Answer (score 1):

Hasn't this one been done before? I thought it was simply stored in the MySQL database and that is essentially what you need to reset. In any case, I doubt it's stored in cleartext. It'll likely be a hash so you can't 'read it off' which means you have to go through password reset procedures as outlined below.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/118772/how-to-change-root-password-for-mysql-and-phpmyadmin

https://askubuntu.com/questions/321903/resetting-forgotten-phpmyadmin-password

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23907736/change-mysql-root-password-in-phpmyadmin

Comment: Well, this is about the standard password to login to mysql with `mysql -u root -p`. What I am talking about is the extra layer that phpmyadmin has setup